# How detect is GET request is made by embed "src"?

Tags: php, http-headers

Is there any way to detect in PHP is GET request made by embed src in browser?

```
<img src="xxxxx.php">
```

I was trying use "REFFER", but it's very not good solution.

I don't know lot about http, but maybe if browser use  tag, it send header accept image  or anything like this what i can read in php ?

I just want create script what will display picture if embed, but if open in browser in normal way, like url it will redirect user to other page.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to detect in PHP is GET request made by embed src in browser?

No.

Comment: Adding "this is not possible no matter what language or technologies you are using" would also have put you above the min size threshold. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you hide your files in a folder outside the root, created a PHP file that all images routed through (`image.php?lovely_duck.jpg`) and then looked for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, that would be possible. But you can forge `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and [it isn’t always reliable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

If you’re trying to find a way to stopping people getting your images, they’ll always find a way.

Comment: That header will be the same no matter if the visitor viewed an `<img>` element or followed a link. It won't give you the information the OP was asking for.

Comment: I thought what he meant was if you were to go to the image from say, Google Images or something that isn’t his site, it would redirect away.

Answer (score 0):

You can (but i would NOT suggest it) check the `Accept` header.
If the request was triggered by an `<img src=...` it should NOT contain "text/html".
Also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413930/detect-if-image-is-embedded/29416515#29416515)

But again: i would not suggest using this.
At the moment that will break the download image functionality in firefox and possible other browser.
Additionally it won't prevent "evil guys" to download all your images because they simply can set the required HTTP header.