# Detect if image is embedded

Tags: php, image, detection

I started to write my own image host but I have a little problem:

I want to display an HTML page if you directly view the link (eg. Domain.com/img/123) via the browser, and an image if you embed the link via

```html
<img src="Domain.com/img/123">
```

to faciliate the use.

Is it possible to detect whether the link is directly viewed or the link is embedded with PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `htaccess` file for this purpose:

When the browser loads an embedded image, he already knows the format to expect, so he will add this information to the `HTTP:Accept` headers when requesting the file. (or at least reduce it to any image-type)

If the Browser is Accessing a file directly (url in the addressbar) he does not know this, so he will add `text/html` to the `HTTP:Accept` Header.

Extract from chrome:

direct: `Accept text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*`

embedded: `Accept image/png, image/svg+xml, image/*;q=0.8, */*;q=0.5`

Use this information to catch the direct access cases: The example bellow will redirect Access on `http://localhost/test/myimage.gif` to `index.php?url=/test/myimage.gif`.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.gif        # redirect gifs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*index\.php  # make sure there is no loop
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} .*text/html.*  # redirect direct access
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/test/index.php?url=$1 [R,L]
```

another file like `http://localhost/test/test.php` could properly use `<img src="http://localhost/test/myimage.gif" />` No redirect will happen, since no `Accept: text/html` will be send.

Keep in mind, that this is a little bad to *test*: Once you had the image embedded somewhere, the browser cache will no longer load data when you access the image directly. Hence it will look like *direct access* is possible. But if you hit F5 to refresh the cached image, the redirect will apply. 
(Leave debugging tools open to have the cache disabled)

---

## Update

As to your comment. I overlooked that you want to use an artifical url to present the image at any time. This changes the way to design the htaccess ofc.

The following htaccess should behave as you expect:

- If the Request Uri ends with slash followed by numbers only (i.e. `/2537263`) it is considered to be eligible for rewrite.
- If it is diret access (Http-Accept says *text/html*) it is rewritten to `wrapperpage.php`
- If it is embedded access (HTTP-Accept says **not** *text/html) it is rewritten to `image.php`

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /\d+$   
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} .*text/html.*  
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ http://localhost/test/wrapperpage.php?id=$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /\d+$   
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} !.*text/html.*      
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ http://localhost/test/image.php?id=$1 [R,L]
```

Note: if you ommit the `[R]` Option, users will not see the redirect reflected in the url.

Example page code I used:

wrapperpage.php:

```
THIS IS MY WRAPPER PAGE: 

<br />                   
<img src = "http://localhost/test/<?=$_GET["id"]?>" />
<br />

IMAGE IS WRAPPED.
```

image.php (Your logic to determine the picture goes there i assume)

```
<?php

//Load Image
$id = $_GET["id"];

//pseudoloading based on id... 
// loading... 
// done. 
$image = imagecreatefromgif("apache_pb.gif"); 

//output image as png.
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);

?>
```

So:

- `http://localhost/test/1234` in browser -> `wrapperpage.php?id=1234`
- `http://localhost/test/1234` embedded -> `image.php?id=1234`
- `http://localhost/test/image.php?id=1234` -> Returns png-image.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} .*text/html.*  # redirect direct access
is not working.This is my .htaccess:
http://pastebin.com/Fvme9rqu

Comment: @aaerix Your problem is `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` Here you are saying: *only apply the rule, if that file does not exist* - which does not make sence for the purpose you would to use it.

Comment: @aaerix I updated my question so it matches your artifical urls.

Comment: I did not even know that it is possible! :D Thank you so much!

Comment: Just a warning: This will break the ability to download the image and right click -> View image in firefox (and probably other browsers) as ff will send the default Access header (including "text/html" for these actions.  I would not suggest to use this method at all TBH.

Comment: Wouldn't you also have the `Referer`-header, whenever a request is for an image _referred_ by an HTML text?

Comment: @SleepProgger well, I guess breaking "rightclick->ViewImage" is exactly what is desired, so you cannot access the file directly.